# Ubuntu server: How to pipe / scroll through search results of a certain command

Tags: command-line, server

This is perhaps a really simple thing to do, however, after looking on the internet I can not find the fast answer anywhere.

Suppose that I have this Ubuntu server running in a really small virtualbox.

When I use a command I sometimes can only see a small part of the results. What should I add after `command` to make me able to scroll through the results page by page?

Comment: Please, don't add answers in the body question. You [can answer your own question](http://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer) if you wish.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu thank you for your advise. Is there a way to recuperate the summary I already made then? Or is this lost now with your edit?

Comment: Yes, see http://askubuntu.com/posts/453548/revisions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ANSWER:** scrolling or "piping" through results can be achieved in some interesting ways.

- `more`

Add `| more` after a command. This will enable you to scroll through results line by line by either hitting enter. When you reach the end of the list you return to the command-line. This can also be done by hitting space.

- `less` or `sensible-pager`

Add `| less` after a command. With this you can search through results with the arrow keys, which enables you not only to go up or down, but also to go to the right and left. You explicitly need to leave to command-line with `q`. There is a whole bunch of other useful commands to add to this one.

- `most`

Using `most` adds some more functionality to `more` and is used in the same way as `less`. I had to enable/install this first however. What I liked about this one is that you can see your progress in the results in the form of a percentage and current line/column.

My favorite would be `less` because it is the most easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `| more`  For example

```
ls -la | more
```

It shows the top bit of the results and you can then use space or the down arrow to navigate downwards.   Similarly, use it with any other command that produces too much for you to see at once.

For a bigger screen experience though, consider SSHing into the guest OS.

Comment: `most` and `less` are also available.

Comment: @Shah with more `more` you can not scroll with the arrow keys it seems. Only space or enter works.

Answer (score 1):

I'd pipe it through `less`

```
command | less
```

Bit of a nicer feature set than `more` IMO.

Answer (score 1):

What about `sensible-pager` from the [`sensible-utils`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/sensible-utils/) package which is installed by default in Ubuntu:

```
command | sensible-pager
```