# Can't scroll up in terminal version of Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

I am using Ubuntu 22.04, command line version.

I am unable to use the standard commands to see prior terminal output(cntrl, scroll up/down) or have the ability to enter into highlight mode.

No idea what to do.

Comment: Related: [Ubuntu server: How to pipe / scroll through search results of a certain command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/453548/ubuntu-server-how-to-pipe-scroll-through-search-results-of-a-certain-command)

Comment: Why can't I use the normal commands present on Ubuntu desktop?

Comment: What do you mean by "cntrl, scroll up/down"? What's that "cntrl"? If you're on the text console and wish to scroll back by pressing Shift+PageUp, that feature was removed from the Linux kernel a few years ago.

Comment: What do you mean by "enter into highlight mode"? I have no idea what you mean by that "highlight mode". What buttons do you press exactly, what do you expect to happen, and what happens instead?

Comment: What do you mean by "Why can't I use the normal commands"? Give us examples. What do you _exactly_ do, what do you expect to happen, what happens instead? For example, you try to execute the command "ls", you type "ls" and then press Enter, and then instead of listing the files you see a particular error message (what then, exactly)? As your questions are phrased currently, it's pretty impossible to guess what your problems are.